# as3 increase about of (red , green , blue) in colour

Tags: actionscript-3, colors

I want to build a slider so the user can change the colour of there player icon , so it will be three sliders , one red , one blue , one green, any idea on how to do it?

```
e.g 
var icon_colour:uint;
icon_colour.red ++;
```

So i you know that code code is made up with 3 sections 0xff (red) ff(green) ff(blue)
how would i change ff(of red as an example) so it will like lighter or darker?

Comment: That's a really generic question. You're going to have to be more specific. Here's how you have to change colours in AS http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3colortransform/

Comment: @CarlSaldanha i added more info

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it was ColorTransform.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out  republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3colortransform , then you go on colour ColorTransform